# Where is located the ssh keys

Tags: linux, ssh

I have generated a new ssh key "`ssh-keygen -t rsa`" named `foo_rsa` but when I list all the file in `~/.ssh` I can't found `foo_rsa`. Only these files are present : `authorized_keys config known_hosts known_hosts.old`. but when I try to regenerate a new ssh-key named 'foo_rsa'I have a warning : ...key already exists. Is there a another default folder for ssh keys.

Comment: Please post your full command, or just use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f foo_rsa`. And ensure your working directory is `.ssh` while doing that.

Comment: How did you name your ssh key?

Comment: `ssh-keygen -t rsa -f foo_rsa` ... `foo_rsa already exists.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating your ssh key, you should have been prompted for the filename.

```
    ssh-keygen -t rsa
    // Enter your filename
```

You can also try to find

```
sudo find / -name id_rsa
```

where `id_rsa` would be the default or you can sub in your entered filename.  In your example,

```
sudo find / -name foo_rsa
```

**EDIT:**
Tell your ssh agent where to find your key by using the ssh config file.  Create `~/.ssh/config` with contents

```
    # Applies to all hosts
    IdentityFile /path/to/key/id_rsa  

   # Host-specific
   Host mydomain.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/another_rsa

   Host 10.10.10.10
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/third_rsa
```

Comment: ok Thks! it was on `/home/guinslym/foo_rsa  /home/guinslym/foo_rsa.pub`. Isn't it supposed to be on .ssh?

Comment: It can be anywhere on your system but you will need to tell your ssh agent where to find it.  Use ssh config.  See updated answer.

Comment: Ok thks! Which configuration is by default? On my desktop key.pub are in ~/.ssh but on my laptop it's on /home/user/key.pub?